# Unexpected result converting a vector to a raster in GRASS 7.0.0

Tags: grass-gis

My purpose is to create a DEM raster in GRASS 7.0.0 starting from a shapefile containing contour lines.

The attributes table has a field named QUOTE_INT containing the elevation as integer.

I started importing the shapefile with the command v.in.ogr.

Here I'm stuck because when I run the command v.to.rast I obtain a raster filled monochromatically instead of a raster containing the contour lines coloured based on their elevation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solved it. it was related to the region resolution (I thought that the measurement unit for the field Grid resolution 2D was meter and I inserted the value 1 in that field because I wanted the region to have a 1m res, but printing the output I saw that the region had only 1 cell in that way... so I deduced that the measurement unit for that field was degree).

I solved it changing the number of rows and columns of the region before running the command v.to.rast.

Comment: We need to know the error message in order to help you...

Answer (score 1):

If you post the exact command you are using, it should be:

```
v.to rast input=<your contour input vector> output=ctour_raster use=attr column=QUOTE_INT
```

Then use the contour raster in r.surf.contour:

```
r.surf.contour input=ctour_raster output=dem
```

For more options you can read [this wiki page](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example from the [GRASS wiki](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM).

Since you get a monochromatical raster I assume you have to apply [r.colors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.colors.html). You can use e.g. `srtm` or `terrain` as color code. See also: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Color_tables